# Istio Service Mesh Side Car Injection Fail

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, istio-sidecar

While testing istio service mesh, I used one of the sample deployment called 'book-review'. I started the deployment + service with `kubectl create -f ./samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml`. After this I did `istio analyse` and noticed I need to setup "default" namespace label as istio-injected. However, even after injecting istio and **restarting** deployments I get the same error.

```
The pod default/ratings-v1-565788b498-n7s5m is missing the Istio proxy. This can often be resolved by restarting or redeploying the workload.
```

Istio Injection Fails

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the application and then redeploy it. You have to label the namespace _before_ you deploy any workloads.

Comment: You can simply do `kubectl delete -f <your_yaml>` and `kubectl apply -f <your_yaml>` once the clean-up finishes. Wait for pods to run `2/2` meaning application + sidecar both containers will be running.